# what exactly is build the site (jekyll)?

Tags: jekyll

this's a super noob question but, what exactly is "build the site" running this command:

```
`~/myblog $ bundle exec jekyll serve`
```

is this to start the server?, because I'm currently using `$ jekyll serve` :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in its [Quick-start guide](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/), this command will build the site on the preview server.

## Update:

There is a difference between `jekyll serve` and `bundle exec jekyll serve`:

> The `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files inform Bundler about the gem requirements in your site. If your site doesn’t have these Gemfiles, you can omit `bundle exec` and just run `jekyll serve`.
>
> When you run `bundle exec jekyll serve`, Bundler uses the gems and versions as specified in `Gemfile.lock` to ensure your Jekyll site builds with no compatibility or dependency conflicts.

## Update 2:

In simple words, "build the site" means the Bundler will use the gems and versions specified in `Gemfile.lock` to ensure your Jekyll site builds with no compatibility or dependency conflicts and then will run your site on the preview or local server.

Comment: I already read the guide, but I don't know what is "build the site", because I installed my site without run this command.

Comment: @Blueh, check my answer, I updated it. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm not a jekyll user but I don't think you've answered the question. He is asking what 'build the site' means in the docs. Although he seems to be able to use jekyll he is confused as to what means what

Comment: I've posted an answer just in case the accepted answer seems unsatisfying..

Answer (score 1):

The `serve` command is actually an ***extension of the `build` command***.
i.e., when a Jekyll user runs `jekyll serve` or `bundle exec jekyll serve`, Jekyll first runs the `jekyll build` command internally and *then starts the local server* to host the generated site.

So what exactly is this `build the site`? Well, Jekyll being a **static-site generator** *generates* your site using the `build` command.

Therefore, whether you run `jekyll build` or `jekyll serve`, a default jekyll site gets *built* or *generated* into the `./_site` folder. The minor difference with running the `serve` command being Jekyll will proceed to start a local web-server and mount the built / generated site onto the server so that you can navigate the site via `http://localhost:4000`